# Binding Resultset Data to Getter Setter Method to Form JSON String

Tags: java, android, rest, jersey

I am trying to form a JSON using GSON.
But my final JSON formed returns null.My result set contains all the available data but the problem persist when forming JSON from resultset.

Any Help,My code below.

My DAO CLASS--ServiceAccess

```
package com.rest.bean;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

import com.rest.constants.Constants;


public class ServiceAccess 
{
    public ArrayList<ServiceBean> GetServices() throws Exception
    {

        ArrayList<ServiceBean> feedServices = new ArrayList<ServiceBean>();
        try
        {

            Connection con;
            Statement stmt=null;

             Class.forName(Constants.dbClass);
                 con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@XX.XX.XX.XXX:152X:orcl10g","XXXX","XXXXX");
             stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
             String sqlQuery1="select SSCODE as SERVICECODE,SSDESC as SERVICEDESC from ksubservice order by SSCODE";
             System.out.println("printing sql query1 :"+sqlQuery1);
             ResultSet rst = stmt.executeQuery(sqlQuery1);

             while (rst.next()) 
             {


            ServiceBean ServiceObjects=new ServiceBean();
            ServiceObjects.setServiceCode(rst.getString("SERVICECODE").toString());   
            ServiceObjects.setServiceDesc(rst.getString("SERVICEDESC").toString()); 


        }
        System.out.println(feedServices);
        return feedServices;


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }



    }


}
```

My Bean Class--ServiceBean

```
package com.rest.bean;

public class ServiceBean 
{

private String ServiceCode;
private String ServiceDesc;

public String getServiceCode()
{
    return ServiceCode;
}

public void setServiceCode(String ServiceCode)
{
    this.ServiceCode=ServiceCode;
}

public String getServiceDesc()
{
    return ServiceDesc; 
}

public void setServiceDesc(String ServiceDesc)
{
    this.ServiceDesc=ServiceDesc;
}

}
```

My Model Class--ServiceArray

```
package com.rest.bean;



import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.rest.database.DBConnection;


public class ServiceArray 
{

    public ArrayList<ServiceBean> GetServices()throws Exception
    {
    ArrayList<ServiceBean> serviceData = null;
    try
    {
     ServiceAccess accessObjects=new ServiceAccess();
     serviceData=accessObjects.GetServices();

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
     throw e;
    }
    return serviceData;

    }


}
```

My JsonObject Converter Class

```
package com.rest.bean;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.rest.bean.ServiceBean;

public class DataTransformer 
{

    public static String DataFeed(ArrayList<ServiceBean> feedData)
    {
    String feeds = null;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    feeds = gson.toJson(feedData);
    return feeds;
    }



}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  In order to get the best results from asking here, please take a moment to review [how to ask a good question of this nature](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and maybe improve your question.

Comment: Hi GreenAsJade,i have full formend my question,and require help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Json Http Request

```
String url = "http://www.myurl.com/data.php";

BufferedReader inStream = null; 
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(url);

try {

       HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);
       inStream = new BufferedReader(
       new InputStreamReader(
       response.getEntity().getContent()));

       StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("");
       String line = "";

       while ((line = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
            inStream.close();

            reply = buffer.toString();  
        } catch (Exception e) {
                //Handle Exception
        }
```

This should get the json reply if it is issued corrected form the url

Answer (score 1):

Following is my best use of Gson maybe it can help..

For this example the Json reply is in a form of a string web response:

Note : reply is a string containing json data

Note : JsonClass is a normal class implementation containing properties matching the Json elements in the reply

```
JSONArray array = new HttpManager().getJsonArrayFromReply(reply);


for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = (JSONObject) array.get(i);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                return null;
            }

            Gson gson = new Gson();

            JsonClass jsonClass = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(), JsonClass.class);


        }
```

Comment: hi Johan V,I am not able to form a JSON String yet,so i get web service reply as NULL.

Comment: ok, have you tried the link you are getting the data from in a browser and see if a Json reply appears?, if yes..do you consider using Volley for your Network requests? , if you need some help with volley pls tell me

Comment: In the meantime i'm posting you default json http request in android

Comment: try my new answer to get a json reply from a webservice..once you have the json reply in a string you can proceed with gson as my previous answer

Comment: Johan V,i goin with gson because,i created a jsonArray with string writer,I could read the json in my android device.But since the data was bulk approx.500 more records the service would end.I read somewhere that gson can handle bulk data.I have not tried Volley.Can it handel Bulk data?

Comment: Volley and Retrofit can deal with large amount of data pretty fast...i dont have experience with Retrofit though